# How are regular expressions processed?

Tags: regex

How are regular expressions processed?

Comment: This needs more context. There are many different techniques.

Comment: I think you need to be a little bit more specific here, unless you want answers like "the computer does that".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A regular expression describes a ruleset for a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). It generally moves over a string one character at a time, making decisions based on what happened on previous characters and what is described in the regex.

Any regex can also be written as a loop over a string one character at a time. Some of these could be fairly simple, but the power of regex is found when what appears to be a simple regex, with a few lookbehinds and subgroups would take a thousand lines of code to reproduce in your own state machine.

Answer (score 6):

Regular expressions can be modeled as a [Deterministic Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine).  That would probably be a good place to start if you wanted to "process" one.

Comment: I think regular expressions are non-deterministic finite state machines  (Jurafsky & Martin, Speach and Lnaguage Processing, 2000, Prentice Hall - Chapter 2)

Comment: @James.  More commonly, yes they are.  The often imitated Perl implementation is non-deterministic.  There are some engines that are deterministic though.  See my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

This question is very broad. This is not a complete answer but Jeff Moser has an excellent write-up on his blog that walks through .NET's regex process: [How .NET Regular Expressions Really Work](http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html)

I suspect other answers will shed light on other areas of regular expressions unless your question is updated to be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on which regex implementation you're referring to.

There are 2 common but different techniques used in regex engines:

1. [Nondeterministic Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_Finite_Automaton)
2. [Deterministic Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite-state_machine)

This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yzc2yb0.aspx) explains several techniques implemented in various engines and then goes onto explain .NET's implementation and why Microsoft chose what they chose for .NET.

They go even more in-depth in the various articles you see listed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e347654k.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

http://www.moserware.com/2009/03/how-net-regular-expressions-really-work.html

Answer (score 0):

Despite what everyone here says about state machines, you can write a remarkably simple regex recogniser using recursive techiques with very little state. There are examples of these in two of Brian Kernighan's books Software Tools In Pascal and [The Practice Of Programming](http://plan9.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/tpop/).